# filterexpression returns "wrong" result

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a filterexpression that enables you to filter the results from a gridview.

I have two dropdownlists (5 and 6 in the filterexpression, the rest is textboxes and works ine) where you can select a specific predefined range to filter your results by.

My filterexpression is as follows:

```
FilterExpression="CompanyName LIKE '{0}%' AND CityName like '{1}%' AND Convert(Zipcode, 'System.String') like '{2}%' AND Convert(ActionID, 'System.String') like '{4}%' AND Convert(Employees, 'System.String') like '{5}%' or (Convert(Zipcode, 'System.String') >= '{2}%' AND Convert(Zipcode, 'System.String')  <= '{3}%') or (Convert(Employees, 'System.String') >= '{5}%' AND Convert(Employees, 'System.String')  <= '{6}%')">
```

My problem is regarding the number of employees. In the available values for the number of employees I have 99, 199, 499, 999 and 1000.

If I choose the first value to be 99 and the second to be 199, I will also get the results for companies that have 999 employees, because it includes 99. However this logically shouldn't happen, as 999 is out of the selected range.

Any idea how to fix this?

edit: Forgot to mention, I have ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false in my controlparamters. So I don't have to fill out each and every textbox to get a result.

Regarding the conversion, it is something I have to do, otherwise it wont show any data in the gridview, unless I specify a filter.

Answer (score 3):

If you add some newlines you see what is going on

```
CompanyName LIKE '{0}%'
AND CityName like '{1}%' 
AND Convert(Zipcode, 'System.String') like '{2}%' 
AND Convert(ActionID, 'System.String') like '{4}%'
AND Convert(Employees, 'System.String') like '{5}%' 

or 
(
    Convert(Zipcode, 'System.String') >= '{2}%' 
    AND Convert(Zipcode, 'System.String')  <= '{3}%'
) 
or 
(
    Convert(Employees, 'System.String') >= '{5}%' 
    AND Convert(Employees, 'System.String')  <= '{6}%'
)
```

Basically, if your first block (with the four ANDs) matches, a record is shown, even if none of the OR blocks match.

Look close at `AND Convert(Employees, 'System.String') like '{5}%'` which means

```
 AND Employees LIKE '99%'
```

That is also true for 999. I suggest you remove the Emplyee filter from the first block.

**UPDATE**

There is another issue, in your OR expression you are using the `>=` and `<=` operator with a string. I can't predict how that evaluates but I suggest you convert Employees to int and remove the `%` at the end.

```
or 
(
    Convert(Employees, 'System.Int32') >= {5}
    AND Convert(Employees, 'System.Int32')  <= {6}
)
```

Comment: But if I remove then how am I supposed to filter out a specific range?

Comment: @dQlle You should just remove the `AND Employees LIKE '99%'` part which will match `everything starting with 99` in your case. The other  parth with `>= and <=` should already do what you want (if casted to number).

Comment: I tried your suggestion by changing it to int, but then I have a new problem. It throws some kind of syntax errror, because int and string doesnt really like it when there is >= and <=. 

If I go with my original code, it works perfectly fine, if I choose another range, say from 199 to 499.

Comment: @dQlle `if I choose another range, say from 199 to 499` That is not true, this would match 1990, too.